# Juggling the values of a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In a table tab I have a column with the name of col1 and it has 5 rows with values 1 to 5.

```
col1  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5
```

Now I want to write a select query which will juggle the values in col1,distribute it and put those values in new column.
Below output will help you understand my requirement.

```
col1 New_col  
1     3  
2     5  
3     4  
4     1  
5     2
```

**Note**: If 1 is changed to 3, then no other value in col1 after juggling should result in 3. i have to do it for 500 rows, i am taking a small example for better understanding.

Please let me know if you require further clarification.

Comment: Does all 500 rows has numbers from 1 to 500 sequentially ??

Comment: @Nikhil Yes all rows has 1 to 500 sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

This is a step by step approach:

[Try it at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff8f3/31)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t ( i int );
insert into t values (1);
insert into t values (2);
insert into t values (3);
insert into t values (4);
insert into t values (5);
```

**Step by step query**:

```
with

/*add a random column to shuffle*/
a as
( select i, dbms_random.value as o 
  from t),

/*get last element to pair it with the first*/
b as
( select i, 
         o, 
         last_Value(i) over (ORDER BY o asc 
                             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
                             AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS i2
  from a)

/*pair each element with the next one, take the last one as default*/  
select i, LAG(i, 1, i2 ) OVER (ORDER BY o ) AS i3
from b
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff8f3/31/0)**:

```
| I | I3 |
|---|----|
| 2 |  5 |
| 1 |  2 |
| 3 |  1 |
| 4 |  3 |
| 5 |  4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
  SELECT row_number() over (order by 1) col, col1 new_col
  FROM   tab
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc310388f34417d639b2d6e3db74bbaf)

Comment: what if we use order by NULL in row_number() ??

Comment: @Nikhil true is that my current version is an unnecessary function call. I will change it